# SSRS 2012 Parameter settings

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am creating a report with columns say A,B,C,D,E. I am setting up a drill down on the column A that fetches one more report with Columns
G,H,I,J. The values for the columns G,H,I are from taken the columns A B C. For the column J,I need to pass a parameter explicitly(not from the source report). I set that parameter in
the properties section -> Available Values and mentioned the values. I ran the main report and get the following error

The Parameter J is a missing value

I am pretty much new to the SSRS projects and would be great if I could any assistance on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are putting parameter J in the wrong place. It doesn't go in the Parameters collection for the main report but in the parameters that are passed to the sub-report.

Right-click the cell with the drill-down and select `Text Box Properties...`. Choose `Action` from the left-hand menu and it will show the drill-down report. Under this it says `Use these parameters to run the report:`

Add the parameters of the sub-report and the values you are passing. You can use an expression to provide the value for parameter J.